# How to add a column based on the values of a list of lists in python? No libraries

Tags: python, list, arraylist, nested-lists

How to add a column based on one of the values of a list of lists in python?

I have the following list and I need to add a new column based on the value of Currency.

If Pound , Euro = Amount *0.9
If USD , Euro =Amount *1.2
I need to code without libraries.

```
[['Buyer', 'Seller', 'Amount', 'Property_Type','Currency'], 
['100', '200', '4923', 'c', 'Pound'], 
['600', '429', '838672', 'a', 'USD'],
['650', '400', '8672', 'a', 'Euro']
```

Result

```
[['Buyer', 'Seller', 'Amount', 'Property_Type', 'Currency', 'Euro'], 
['100', '200', '5000', 'c', 'Livre', '6000'], 
['600', '429', '10000', 'a', 'USD', '9000'],
['650', '400', '8600', 'a', 'Euro', '8600']
```

Thank you very much, any readings on how to import a csv and manipulate it, without libraries, would be much appreciated.

Comment: NEither of your code samples show a list of lists. Also have you looked into using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are always in the same order...

```
EXCH_RATES = {
    'Pound': Decimal('0.9'),
    'USD': Decimal('1.2'),
    'Euro': 1,
}
rows[0].append('Euro')
for row in rows[1:]:
  exch_rate = EXCH_RATES[row[4]]
  row.append(str(exch_rate * Decimal[row[2]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the last item in the list inside the list then check what its currency is then change the amount like so:

```py
lst = [['Buyer', 'Seller', 'Amount', 'Property_Type','Currency'], ['100', '200', '4923', 'c', 'Pound'], ['600', '429', '838672', 'a', 'USD'], ['650', '400', '8672', 'a', 'Euro']]
for i in range(3):
    if lst[i][3] == 'Pound':
        lst[i].append(str(int(lst[i][2]) * 0.9))
    elif lst[i][3] == 'USD':
        lst[i].append(str(int(lst[i][2]) * 1.2))
    else:
        lst[i].append(lst[i][2])
```

Although you would be better storing the data in a csv file but then you would have to use the csv library.

Tell me if this helps and if you want to use the csv library tell me so I can tell you how to use it.